# Replace nested object with an object from another file in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file that has the following structures

```
{
  "a":"aval",
  "b":{},
  "c":"cval"
}
```

I have another json file with following content

```
{
  "b1":"b1val","b2":"b2val"
}
```

I want to shove the json object from file 2 into "b" from file 1

```
{
  "a":"aval",
  "b":{
      "b1":"b1val","b2":"b2val"
  },
  "c":"cval"
}
```

how do i do this with JQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming file #2 may not be empty, you can simply assign `input` to `.b`.

```sh
jq '.b = input' file1 file2
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/lQTyx5_83R)</sup>

Otherwise you'd use the following to retain the original value of `.b` when file #2 is empty.

```sh
jq -n 'input | .b = first(inputs, .b)' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks a million, I spent so much time on this, there is no way I would have figured this answer.